# Postgresql Partition by column without a primary key

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I'd like to be able to partition a table by `worksite_uuid`. But `worksite_uuid` needs to be nullable and I need `uuid` to be a primary key.

The only way I've been able create the partition is if `worksite_uuid` is not nullable like so:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   uuid uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1mc(),
   worksite_uuid text,
   notes text
)
PARTITION BY LIST(worksite_uuid)

//then add worksite_uuid and uuid as a primary key

create table test_worksite1 partition of test for values in ('1');
create table test_worksite2 partition of test for values in ('2');
```

Does anyone know how I can create a partition with only `uuid` as the primary key and make `worksite_uuid` nullable?

--

Example: I can't do this

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   uuid uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1mc() PRIMARY KEY,
   worksite_uuid text,
   notes text
)
PARTITION BY LIST(worksite_uuid)
```

I get the following error:

> Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns
> DETAIL:  PRIMARY KEY constraint on table "test" lacks column "worksite_uuid" which is part of the partition key.

Answer (score 0):

It is no problem to create a partition for the NULL values:

```
create table test_worksite_null partition of test for values in (NULL);
```

But it is impossible to have a primary key column that is nullable. You just cannot do it.

I see two ways out:

1. You live without a primary key. Instead, create primary keys on each individual partition. That won't guarantee global uniqueness, but almost.
2. You use another value instead of NULL, for example -1.

Comment: This totally works but I can't actually get worksite_uuid to be null if it's a primary key. I've updated my question to show an example of where I am stuck

Comment: I don't want `worksite_uuid` to be a primary key. However, I can't find a way to create the table partition without it. For example, I want to run your above query to partition by null values. However, it doesn't let me because I'm forced to make worksite_uuid non-nullable. Does this make sense?